# Domain of Central Limit Theorem

Tags: normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, parameter-estimation

The central limit theorem says that if you take infinite number of samples ( > 30) from a population, compute their mean values, and collect them, you will reach normal distribution. Is this valid for other parameters?

What I mean in this question is if we take infinite number of samples, compute their variances or any other parameter, and collect them, do we construct a normal distribution ?

## Answer:

I made some researches to check if we can expand Central Limit Theorem for all parameters, and we could not find an academic or experimental document. However, I wrote its code. By using random number generator, I generated samples of numbers between 1 and 6, which means I imitated rolling dice problem. I created 100 000 samples and each of them consists of 300 observations(numbers). I drew its distribution plot with the help of Seaborn. As a result, Sampling distributions of sample variance and sample standard deviation are also like normal distribution.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem

Comment: This is a good question. You can easily find the answer if you search for something like “distribution of the sample variance” which I assume is what you mean. Also note that “too many” and “accumulate” don’t make much sense.

Comment: Okey, I edited it with the words `infinite` and `collect`.